# Whats the difference between AWS RDS certificate bundle URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I found `https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` in a legacy repository and came to the conclusion this contains RDS certificates as described [here for Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-download-ssl-certificate-for-managed-database). On the contrary, the [RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) proclaims to use `https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem`. What is the difference of the two URLs? Is the first just the "older", "legacy" version?

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently faced with the same issue, and although I did not find an official answer from AWS in the documentation, I think the right one *nowadays* is the one hosted in `truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com`:

- The RDS documentation just mentions the ones hosted on `truststore.pki...`
- You can still download both files and check their certificates with openssl:

  ```bash
  openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile global-bundle.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout | less

  openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout | less
  ```
- You will then see that `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` contains a subset (~30) of the certificates included in `global-bundle.pem` (~100). More regions are included in the latter, and multiple CA variants for RSA vs elliptic curve.

Long story short, I think you are right and the one on `s3.amazonaws.com` is a legacy file just kept not to break existing flows, probably done at the time of the 2015 to 2019 CAs migration.